# boost::asio accepting socket error already open

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

am not sure what is causing this error `Already Open`

```
#include "AsyncServer.h"


AsyncServer::AsyncServer(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, std::string ip, unsigned short port)
    : acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(ip), port))
{

    BeginAccept();
}


AsyncServer::~AsyncServer()
{
}


void AsyncServer::BeginAccept(){
    tcp::socket temp = tcp::socket(acceptor.get_io_service());
    acceptor.async_accept(temp, boost::bind(&AsyncServer::EndAccept, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void AsyncServer::EndAccept(const boost::system::error_code& error){

    if (!error)
    {
        //continue with connection
        std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << error.message() <<std::endl;
    }

    BeginAccept();
}
```

what am trying to do is pass the socket and the error to `EndAccept` but it breaks and the error is `Already Open` , I don't know what's wrong here !

Answer (score 4):

`temp` is a local object, it gets destroyed immediately on `BeginAccept` exit. This means that `async_accept` works with a danging reference, which is undefined behavior.

Make `temp` a member (it would be also a good idea to give it more meaningful name).